# Migrating iCloud to local persistent store

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, core-data-migration

I am running out of ideas how could I possibly migrate the iCloud store to local store. 
From one side I get crash with message:

`The specified persistent store was not found`

on the other side

`NSUnderlyingException = "Can't add the same store twice"`

The point is there is no clear tutorial how to migrate stores (Or at least I can't find). Everything I found so far was pieces of information spread across net and couldn't make very much sense.

This is my code:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) cloudPersistentStoreCoordinator {
    self.storeURL = [[MMNUtilities localDocumentsURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myapp.sqlite"];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
    NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"myapp"};

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.persistentStore = [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                     configuration:nil
                                                                               URL:self.storeURL
                                                                           options:storeOptions
                                                                             error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (BOOL) didMigrateiCloudStoreToLocalStore {
    NSError *error = nil;

    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [self cloudPersistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSDictionary *storeOptions      = @{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"myapp",
                                        NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption : @YES};

    NSPersistentStore *localStore   = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:self.persistentStore  <<< Exception happens here 
                                                                                        toURL:self.storeURL
                                                                                      options:storeOptions
                                                                                     withType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                                        error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:HnHCoreDataPersistentStoreMigrationFailed object:self];
        return NO;
    }

    return [self reloadStore:localStore];
}
```

I got following message in console:

`CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:PF_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_NAME URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EFC750F6-D10E-4B8A-9F83-C77621218DB7/Documents/myapp.sqlite options:{
    NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption = 1;
    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey = myapp;
    "_NSNotifyObserversOfStoreChange" = 0;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134080 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134080.)" UserInfo=0x15deee80 {NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice} with userInfo dictionary {
    NSUnderlyingException = "Can't add the same store twice";
}`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new local store **with a different name**.

Comment: Do you mean `myapp.sqlite` should have different name for iCloud and Local ? And it doesn't matter they stored in different location ?